# what should I do for this problem in the tsconfig.json?

Tags: typescript, config, vuejs3

I got this error: "message": "Cannot find type definition file for 'vite/cli'.\n  The file is in the program because:\n    Entry point of type library 'vite/cli' specified in compilerOptions"

Please help me check this problem.

Comment: can you please look into this 
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27956